# localhost redirigido a una ip externa EXPRESSJS

Tags: express, google-chrome

Cuando introduzco localhost:3000 en chromium me redirige a google.es y no puedo evitar este comportamiento, he investigado a que puede deberse y no doy con una solución.

En mozilla no me ocurre.
Mi sistema es ubuntu 18.04, he investigado el archivo etc/hosts y no parece haber nada extraño:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   'mi nombre'-H81M-DS2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

También he observado que en chromium se instala una entrada en otros motores de búsqueda con el campo buscador y palabra clave localhost que hace referencia a una URL de consulta que apunta hacia esa dirección google.es.
El caso  es que he borrado esa entrada pero me sigue haciendo la redireccion.

También recuerdo que he estado practicando con la librería de javascript express, el caso es que en un momento dado, creo recordar , hice una redireccion en el codigo de la siguiente forma :

`res.redirect('https://google.es')`

o algo similar el caso es que no soy capaz de encontrarlo , ya se que no debería de tener nada que ver a no ser que el proceso haya quedado en memoria lo cual no creo.

No tengo la mas remota idea de que proceso es el que esta redirigiendo, se aceptan sugerencias  o pruebas gracias
Pensandolo bien creo que tiene que deberse a alguna condicion exclusiva de chromium ya que el redireccionamiento no me ocurre en mozilla

Comment: mantén abierta la consola con la opción de des-habilitar cache, seguramente chrome recuerde el redirect

Comment: gracias efectivamente era un problema de cache de chrome